# Array output difficulties

Tags: c, arrays, output

I have been practising with arrays for a bit and I have encountered a problem I can't seem to find the answer for. I am trying to display the numbers the user enters, however they are not turning out as I expected. It should be in a form of a column.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
   double A[5], B[5];
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
   {
    printf("Enter 5 numbers for column A: ");
    scanf("%lf", &A[i]);
   }
   for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
   {
    printf("Enter 5 numbers for column B: ");
    scanf("%lf", &B[i]);
   }
   printf("A = (%f)  B = (%f) \n", A[i], B[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

The printf statement seems to be correct however numbers are not showing in the output.

Comment: Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) could be useful here. Hint: How many times are you reading input? How many times are you printing output?

Comment: Add a bracket after main ,you forgot it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude has the answer, I think

Comment: By the time you invoke printf,  i == 5.And of course I assume that your aim is to print the last number of every array , right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask yourself, what is the value of `i`, when printing the final output.
You should also ask yourself, what is in array `A` and `B` at `index i`.

Given these are understood, we can display the content of an array in the same fashion as it is filled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  double A[5], B[5];
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
      printf("Enter 5 numbers for column A: ");
      scanf("%lf", &A[i]);
    }
  for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
      printf("Enter 5 numbers for column B: ");
      scanf("%lf", &B[i]);
    }
  for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
    {
      printf("A = (%f)  B = (%f) \n", A[i], B[i]);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Tsakiroglou Fotis, you forgot to add bracket after the main function and also you are not looping the final print statement to print all the elements. Try using editors that does take care of such mistakes. here is your corrected code

```html
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void){
double A[5], B[5];
int i;
for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
    printf("Enter 5 numbers for column A: ");
    scanf("%lf", &A[i]);
}
for(i=0; i<=4; i++)
{
    printf("Enter 5 numbers for column B: ");
    scanf("%lf", &B[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<5; i++){
  printf("A = (%f)  B = (%f) \n", A[i], B[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```